# Getting permission_denied at /items: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm defining a firebase rule to read data by userId. userId is a flag on each data created by a user, which is, of course, the user uid.

her's the rule below:

```
{
    "rules": {
      "items": {
        "$itemId": {
         ".read": "auth !== null && root.child('items/$itemId/userId').val() === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And I'm accessing data on the client side like so:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/items`)
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      const places = []
      const data = snapshot.val();
      for (let key in data) {
        places.push({
          ...data[key],
          key: key
        });
      }
    })
```

I want data access to the owner based on their userId flag on each item.

A sample of the data structure below:

Answer (score 1):

According to the Firebase documentation [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters). However last year (2018) **query rules** were introduced, I think the [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/01/introducing-query-based-security-rules.html?m=1) is better than the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules) for understanding this.

So to keep your current data structure your rule should change to:

```
{
    "rules": {
      "items": {
         ".read": "query.orderByChild == 'userId' && query.equalTo == auth.uid"
      }
    }
}
```

Then you have to change your query as well:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/items`).orderByChild('userId').equalsTo(userId)...
```

One last thing, it seems your database structure could be pointing to other needs:

- If you want to make your data only accessible for the user who created it and also have an admin that can see everything, then a better solution is to denormalize your data. Your data structure would be:

```
user_items: {
    uid1: {
          key1:{//full object here}
     }
},
items: {
    key1:{//partial item here, just name and photo, think on a list}
},
admins:{
    uid1:true
}
```

Here the admin problem is solved with an admin node, this could be used in conjunction with [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) and [Firebase Functions](https://gist.github.com/cutiko/ca003e0ea134c749b6a9f4615f8c1e99).

- Since there is a *places* *word*, maybe you need to use something else like [geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js) for locations

Comment: thanks for the note, it was helpful. I have added the admin tree with the following rules `:" root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() == true"` and on the client side: `if(firebase.database().ref('/admins').orderByChild(currentUser.uid).equalTo(true))` to return all data for admins but data is not being returned. Any suggestion on how to match the data filter on the client side for the rule provided?